Issues Resolving Swiper Module Paths in Next.js Project
I'm working on a Next.js project and facing issues with resolving Swiper module paths. I've installed Swiper (version 11.1.11), but when I try to import the modules, I get the following errors:
Error: Unable to resolve path to module 'swiper/modules'.  import/no-unresolved
Error: Unable to resolve path to module 'swiper/react'.  import/no-unresolved
Error: Unable to resolve path to module 'swiper/css'.  import/no-unresolved
Error: Unable to resolve path to module 'swiper/css/navigation'.  import/no-unresolved

Environment:

Swiper Version: 11.1.11
Next.js Version: 14.2.7
TypeScript Version: Latest
Node.js Version: 20.17.0

Any Suggestions?
Has anyone else experienced similar issues, or does anyone have insights into what might be going wrong here?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Correct Imports:
I'm using the following import statements:

   import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
   import { Navigation } from 'swiper';
   import 'swiper/css';
   import 'swiper/css/navigation';


Reinstalled Swiper:
I've removed and reinstalled Swiper multiple times using:
yarn remove swiper
yarn add swiper


Updated TypeScript Configuration:
My tsconfig.json is set up as follows:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}


Cleared Cache and Reinstalled Dependencies:
I've tried clearing the cache and reinstalling all dependencies:
rm -rf node_modules
yarn cache clean
yarn install
yarn build


Checked TypeScript Types:
Installed the types for Swiper using:
yarn add -D @types/swiper



